# Most practical way to work with multi-table structure

Tags: r, structure, lapply

I populate a data structure based on a bunch of csv files in a directory showing a time series (yearly) of growth in employment, households, etc for a series of counties (in rows). While I could loop over the length of the `dat` object and stuff each table into a dataframe and then process that in turn, I am intrigued by the `lapply` family of functions to maybe avoid the loop and make the code simpler and much easier to maintain down the line.

Let's say I want to perform an operation on a column which happens to be in all tables in the structure (could be a `grep` for renaming all columns to just the year portion embedded in the name, or converting the `county_id.li8` variable to a `factor` with appropriate factor levels.) I am having trouble properly indexing the structure to get down to the second and third levels and also applying a `lapply` call to those same columns. For example, I can access the county_id.li8 column in ONE of the subtables by

```
> head(dat[1][[1]][1])
  county_id.i8
1            1
2            7
3           17
4           21
5           23
6           24
```

But this works only by plugging in specific indices. In other words, how would I make something like the following work (here assigning letters as factor levels as a generic example for using lapply to work on repeat columns across the tables in the structure).

`lapply(dat[][[]][1],factor, labels=letters[1:9]) #indices ommitted here; looking for general notation for access to the first column in all tables in structure`

Any pointers on how to properly index a couple of levels down across *all* levels, and ultimately how to call the lappy function on columns in the different tables embedded in the structure? (Data below).

```
> dat<-lapply(fileList,read.csv,header=T,sep = "\t")
> dput(dat)
list(structure(list(county_id.i8 = c(1L, 7L, 17L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 
28L, 35L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 43L, 44L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 57L), county_employment_pda_2010.f8 = c(313325, 
102645, 0, 19302, 0, 0, 9340, 0, 483207, 0, 110998, 444452, 0, 
22426, 74123, 0, 0), county_employment_pda_2011.f8 = c(313216, 
102576, 0, 19281, 0, 0, 9338, 0, 483043, 0, 110974, 445445, 0, 
22417, 74017, 0, 0), county_employment_pda_2012.f8 = c(313238, 
102504, 0, 19252, 0, 0, 9333, 0, 482906, 0, 110947, 446132, 0, 
22416, 73971, 0, 0), county_employment_pda_2013.f8 = c(313137, 
102418, 0, 19262, 0, 0, 9352, 0, 482697, 0, 110867, 447037, 0, 
22373, 73946, 0, 0), county_employment_pda_2014.f8 = c(313114, 
102399, 0, 19255, 0, 0, 9357, 0, 482469, 0, 110784, 447622, 0, 
22359, 73874, 0, 0), county_employment_pda_2015.f8 = c(312961, 
102281, 0, 19249, 0, 0, 9357, 0, 482181, 0, 110733, 448479, 0, 
22358, 73877, 0, 0), county_employment_pda_2016.f8 = c(312943, 
102273, 0, 19239, 0, 0, 9329, 0, 481983, 0, 110719, 449118, 0, 
22367, 73848, 0, 0), county_employment_pda_2017.f8 = c(312839, 
102216, 0, 19231, 0, 0, 9329, 0, 481889, 0, 110653, 450126, 0, 
22360, 73789, 0, 0), county_employment_pda_2018.f8 = c(312760, 
102188, 0, 19219, 0, 0, 9331, 0, 481795, 0, 110620, 451350, 0, 
22341, 73748, 0, 0), county_employment_pda_2019.f8 = c(312723, 
102139, 0, 19214, 0, 0, 9316, 0, 481816, 0, 110484, 452171, 0, 
22311, 73725, 0, 0), county_employment_pda_2020.f8 = c(312531, 
102094, 0, 19208, 0, 0, 9316, 0, 481812, 0, 110444, 453251, 0, 
22294, 73681, 0, 0)), .Names = c("county_id.i8", "county_employment_pda_2010.f8", 
"county_employment_pda_2011.f8", "county_employment_pda_2012.f8", 
"county_employment_pda_2013.f8", "county_employment_pda_2014.f8", 
"county_employment_pda_2015.f8", "county_employment_pda_2016.f8", 
"county_employment_pda_2017.f8", "county_employment_pda_2018.f8", 
"county_employment_pda_2019.f8", "county_employment_pda_2020.f8"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L)), structure(list(
    county_id.i8 = c(1L, 7L, 17L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 28L, 35L, 38L, 
    39L, 41L, 43L, 44L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 57L), county_employment_tpp_2010.f8 = c(450548, 
    164024, 0, 76243, 0, 0, 9280, 0, 578345, 0, 201026, 709110, 
    0, 39157, 79052, 0, 0), county_employment_tpp_2011.f8 = c(450309, 
    163934, 0, 76189, 0, 0, 9280, 0, 578065, 0, 200971, 710321, 
    0, 39154, 78941, 0, 0), county_employment_tpp_2012.f8 = c(450223, 
    163828, 0, 76125, 0, 0, 9278, 0, 577849, 0, 200922, 710952, 
    0, 39137, 78894, 0, 0), county_employment_tpp_2013.f8 = c(450078, 
    163780, 0, 76119, 0, 0, 9297, 0, 577584, 0, 200821, 712099, 
    0, 39123, 78858, 0, 0), county_employment_tpp_2014.f8 = c(449954, 
    163635, 0, 76071, 0, 0, 9297, 0, 577275, 0, 200757, 713066, 
    0, 39093, 78754, 0, 0), county_employment_tpp_2015.f8 = c(449743, 
    163455, 0, 76039, 0, 0, 9298, 0, 576946, 0, 200697, 713844, 
    0, 39095, 78671, 0, 0), county_employment_tpp_2016.f8 = c(449702, 
    163416, 0, 76012, 0, 0, 9270, 0, 576679, 0, 200621, 714573, 
    0, 39095, 78608, 0, 0), county_employment_tpp_2017.f8 = c(449493, 
    163366, 0, 75941, 0, 0, 9264, 0, 576523, 0, 200540, 715484, 
    0, 39093, 78554, 0, 0), county_employment_tpp_2018.f8 = c(449325, 
    163290, 0, 75815, 0, 0, 9266, 0, 576412, 0, 200353, 716977, 
    0, 39052, 78510, 0, 0), county_employment_tpp_2019.f8 = c(449077, 
    163186, 0, 75750, 0, 0, 9251, 0, 576354, 0, 200169, 717829, 
    0, 39018, 78487, 0, 0), county_employment_tpp_2020.f8 = c(448740, 
    163053, 0, 75704, 0, 0, 9250, 0, 576269, 0, 200122, 718708, 
    0, 39008, 78352, 0, 0)), .Names = c("county_id.i8", "county_employment_tpp_2010.f8", 
"county_employment_tpp_2011.f8", "county_employment_tpp_2012.f8", 
"county_employment_tpp_2013.f8", "county_employment_tpp_2014.f8", 
"county_employment_tpp_2015.f8", "county_employment_tpp_2016.f8", 
"county_employment_tpp_2017.f8", "county_employment_tpp_2018.f8", 
"county_employment_tpp_2019.f8", "county_employment_tpp_2020.f8"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L)), structure(list(
    county_id.i8 = c(1L, 7L, 17L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 28L, 35L, 38L, 
    39L, 41L, 43L, 44L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 57L), county_empres_pda_2010.f8 = c(201923, 
    43963, 0, 8772, 0, 0, 815, 0, 186251, 0, 78408, 160782, 0, 
    7238, 38390, 0, 0), county_empres_pda_2011.f8 = c(201783, 
    43849, 0, 8732, 0, 0, 795, 0, 213456, 0, 82832, 167626, 0, 
    7284, 37663, 0, 0), county_empres_pda_2012.f8 = c(202059, 
    44012, 0, 8742, 0, 0, 795, 0, 225552, 0, 87327, 167766, 0, 
    7498, 37518, 0, 0), county_empres_pda_2013.f8 = c(201918, 
    43878, 0, 8715, 0, 0, 789, 0, 232941, 0, 93303, 170896, 0, 
    7502, 38012, 0, 0), county_empres_pda_2014.f8 = c(209007, 
    43640, 0, 8648, 0, 0, 787, 0, 235599, 0, 96654, 174762, 0, 
    7530, 37910, 0, 0), county_empres_pda_2015.f8 = c(212050, 
    43789, 0, 8572, 0, 0, 776, 0, 234853, 0, 100111, 179057, 
    0, 7551, 37825, 0, 0), county_empres_pda_2016.f8 = c(214927, 
    43883, 0, 8531, 0, 0, 764, 0, 239730, 0, 102522, 182816, 
    0, 7518, 37677, 0, 0), county_empres_pda_2017.f8 = c(218551, 
    44331, 0, 8474, 0, 0, 764, 0, 240854, 0, 105426, 186818, 
    0, 7531, 37545, 0, 0), county_empres_pda_2018.f8 = c(220972, 
    45006, 0, 8432, 0, 0, 789, 0, 241628, 0, 107229, 190735, 
    0, 7546, 37596, 0, 0), county_empres_pda_2019.f8 = c(223044, 
    45761, 0, 8379, 0, 0, 818, 0, 244283, 0, 108506, 194185, 
    0, 7521, 37502, 0, 0), county_empres_pda_2020.f8 = c(224509, 
    46506, 0, 8394, 0, 0, 821, 0, 247482, 0, 109911, 197017, 
    0, 7504, 37591, 0, 0)), .Names = c("county_id.i8", "county_empres_pda_2010.f8", 
"county_empres_pda_2011.f8", "county_empres_pda_2012.f8", "county_empres_pda_2013.f8", 
"county_empres_pda_2014.f8", "county_empres_pda_2015.f8", "county_empres_pda_2016.f8", 
"county_empres_pda_2017.f8", "county_empres_pda_2018.f8", "county_empres_pda_2019.f8", 
"county_empres_pda_2020.f8"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L)), structure(list(county_id.i8 = c(1L, 7L, 17L, 21L, 23L, 
24L, 28L, 35L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 43L, 44L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 57L), 
    county_empres_tpp_2010.f8 = c(443752, 155338, 0, 65907, 0, 
    0, 2828, 0, 456214, 0, 206571, 617212, 0, 37273, 48617, 0, 
    0), county_empres_tpp_2011.f8 = c(445080, 154940, 0, 65404, 
    0, 0, 2763, 0, 487189, 0, 212888, 630774, 0, 37297, 47577, 
    0, 0), county_empres_tpp_2012.f8 = c(445075, 155693, 0, 65455, 
    0, 0, 2774, 0, 499931, 0, 219766, 628413, 0, 37542, 47263, 
    0, 0), county_empres_tpp_2013.f8 = c(444322, 155348, 0, 65132, 
    0, 0, 2741, 0, 507989, 0, 228214, 632356, 0, 37431, 47767, 
    0, 0), county_empres_tpp_2014.f8 = c(451863, 154962, 0, 64733, 
    0, 0, 2723, 0, 509617, 0, 234769, 637378, 0, 37330, 47588, 
    0, 0), county_empres_tpp_2015.f8 = c(454943, 155713, 0, 64439, 
    0, 0, 2703, 0, 506948, 0, 241141, 643996, 0, 37412, 47541, 
    0, 0), county_empres_tpp_2016.f8 = c(458014, 156027, 0, 64177, 
    0, 0, 2673, 0, 512542, 0, 245412, 649009, 0, 37347, 47498, 
    0, 0), county_empres_tpp_2017.f8 = c(462516, 156941, 0, 63885, 
    0, 0, 2662, 0, 512233, 0, 249690, 654784, 0, 37323, 47328, 
    0, 0), county_empres_tpp_2018.f8 = c(465893, 158289, 0, 63755, 
    0, 0, 2713, 0, 511619, 0, 252055, 660675, 0, 37380, 47365, 
    0, 0), county_empres_tpp_2019.f8 = c(468709, 159607, 0, 63518, 
    0, 0, 2776, 0, 513150, 0, 253851, 666054, 0, 37360, 47326, 
    0, 0), county_empres_tpp_2020.f8 = c(471780, 160499, 0, 63788, 
    0, 0, 2781, 0, 515528, 0, 255491, 669768, 0, 37373, 47399, 
    0, 0)), .Names = c("county_id.i8", "county_empres_tpp_2010.f8", 
"county_empres_tpp_2011.f8", "county_empres_tpp_2012.f8", "county_empres_tpp_2013.f8", 
"county_empres_tpp_2014.f8", "county_empres_tpp_2015.f8", "county_empres_tpp_2016.f8", 
"county_empres_tpp_2017.f8", "county_empres_tpp_2018.f8", "county_empres_tpp_2019.f8", 
"county_empres_tpp_2020.f8"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L)), structure(list(county_id.i8 = c(1L, 7L, 17L, 21L, 23L, 
24L, 28L, 35L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 43L, 44L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 57L), 
    county_households_pda_2010.f8 = c(170187, 37225, 0, 7006, 
    0, 0, 651, 0, 156702, 0, 53789, 111880, 0, 6479, 29142, 0, 
    0), county_households_pda_2011.f8 = c(169149, 37004, 0, 6943, 
    0, 0, 638, 0, 174237, 0, 56758, 115577, 0, 6497, 28608, 0, 
    0), county_households_pda_2012.f8 = c(169278, 37095, 0, 6955, 
    0, 0, 637, 0, 183566, 0, 60653, 115752, 0, 6634, 28529, 0, 
    0), county_households_pda_2013.f8 = c(169023, 36924, 0, 6933, 
    0, 0, 633, 0, 189987, 0, 65709, 117615, 0, 6626, 29128, 0, 
    0), county_households_pda_2014.f8 = c(174100, 36699, 0, 6889, 
    0, 0, 629, 0, 192437, 0, 68543, 120561, 0, 6643, 29129, 0, 
    0), county_households_pda_2015.f8 = c(176860, 36749, 0, 6839, 
    0, 0, 624, 0, 191746, 0, 71450, 123785, 0, 6646, 29103, 0, 
    0), county_households_pda_2016.f8 = c(179434, 36761, 0, 6812, 
    0, 0, 618, 0, 196075, 0, 73490, 126676, 0, 6616, 28999, 0, 
    0), county_households_pda_2017.f8 = c(182536, 37124, 0, 6772, 
    0, 0, 619, 0, 197431, 0, 75885, 129800, 0, 6618, 28961, 0, 
    0), county_households_pda_2018.f8 = c(184556, 37722, 0, 6736, 
    0, 0, 638, 0, 198440, 0, 77483, 132850, 0, 6620, 29037, 0, 
    0), county_households_pda_2019.f8 = c(186021, 38369, 0, 6698, 
    0, 0, 663, 0, 201268, 0, 78655, 135419, 0, 6591, 29009, 0, 
    0), county_households_pda_2020.f8 = c(187210, 38907, 0, 6717, 
    0, 0, 665, 0, 204334, 0, 79840, 137468, 0, 6569, 29120, 0, 
    0)), .Names = c("county_id.i8", "county_households_pda_2010.f8", 
"county_households_pda_2011.f8", "county_households_pda_2012.f8", 
"county_households_pda_2013.f8", "county_households_pda_2014.f8", 
"county_households_pda_2015.f8", "county_households_pda_2016.f8", 
"county_households_pda_2017.f8", "county_households_pda_2018.f8", 
"county_households_pda_2019.f8", "county_households_pda_2020.f8"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L)), structure(list(
    county_id.i8 = c(1L, 7L, 17L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 28L, 35L, 38L, 
    39L, 41L, 43L, 44L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 57L), county_households_tpp_2010.f8 = c(355208, 
    123536, 0, 50467, 0, 0, 2424, 0, 345393, 0, 138895, 406129, 
    0, 31138, 37070, 0, 0), county_households_tpp_2011.f8 = c(354126, 
    122641, 0, 49973, 0, 0, 2362, 0, 365214, 0, 143132, 413115, 
    0, 30966, 36340, 0, 0), county_households_tpp_2012.f8 = c(354044, 
    123118, 0, 50018, 0, 0, 2363, 0, 375399, 0, 149277, 411874, 
    0, 31089, 36140, 0, 0), county_households_tpp_2013.f8 = c(353169, 
    122709, 0, 49794, 0, 0, 2345, 0, 382912, 0, 156550, 414253, 
    0, 30988, 36782, 0, 0), county_households_tpp_2014.f8 = c(358483, 
    122366, 0, 49502, 0, 0, 2326, 0, 385046, 0, 162182, 418427, 
    0, 30902, 36727, 0, 0), county_households_tpp_2015.f8 = c(361320, 
    122856, 0, 49265, 0, 0, 2309, 0, 383106, 0, 167712, 423715, 
    0, 30946, 36751, 0, 0), county_households_tpp_2016.f8 = c(364010, 
    123010, 0, 49051, 0, 0, 2286, 0, 388265, 0, 171458, 427874, 
    0, 30863, 36738, 0, 0), county_households_tpp_2017.f8 = c(367824, 
    123698, 0, 48857, 0, 0, 2281, 0, 388946, 0, 175097, 432592, 
    0, 30811, 36694, 0, 0), county_households_tpp_2018.f8 = c(370694, 
    124838, 0, 48781, 0, 0, 2329, 0, 389217, 0, 177329, 437403, 
    0, 30821, 36766, 0, 0), county_households_tpp_2019.f8 = c(372758, 
    125835, 0, 48614, 0, 0, 2382, 0, 391713, 0, 179043, 441576, 
    0, 30800, 36802, 0, 0), county_households_tpp_2020.f8 = c(375254, 
    126557, 0, 48859, 0, 0, 2386, 0, 394477, 0, 180661, 444561, 
    0, 30801, 36884, 0, 0)), .Names = c("county_id.i8", "county_households_tpp_2010.f8", 
"county_households_tpp_2011.f8", "county_households_tpp_2012.f8", 
"county_households_tpp_2013.f8", "county_households_tpp_2014.f8", 
"county_households_tpp_2015.f8", "county_households_tpp_2016.f8", 
"county_households_tpp_2017.f8", "county_households_tpp_2018.f8", 
"county_households_tpp_2019.f8", "county_households_tpp_2020.f8"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# I read your data into my_list
library(plyr)
# There is no difference between lappy and llply, except that llply is nicer
# because it preserves names. See ?llply for more information.

new_list <- llply(my_list, function(foo) {
    # Notice that foo now holds the contents of each list item.
    # so class(foo) should give you data.frame
    # you can now access columns just by referencing foo$something
    # rather than using an index
    nicer_data <- melt(foo, id.vars = 1)
    names(nicer_data) <- c("country_id", "year", "value")
    # This returns only the year portion of the string
    nicer_data$year <- substring(nicer_data$year,first=23, last=26)
    return(nicer_data)
    })
```

Comment: It is always amazing to see how many ways--and short ones--there are to Rome. With practice comes elegance. Now, if one wanted to do more operations at the same time (rename column names to years, keep rest as a separate var) would you run that in the same llply call or stuff it in a separate and subsequent process?

Comment: If you want to do more operations, just stuff it inside the `{` `}`. (replace what I put in there). So do whatever you need to do to each piece, and return that to be complied into a new list. It would be easy to write the code for one list item, test it out, then put that into your function to be applied to everything. Good luck!

Comment: You are free to put the result, `new_list` through other `llply` calls to do more, especially if you need to save intermediate data. Otherwise, do as much as you need inside here.

Comment: In the thread of the initial question on indexing specific tables, can I rename values in the 'year' column to just the year for ALL tables at once (so I can later use in ggplot)?